# What are the input parameters for keccak256?

Tags: web3.py, msg.sender

I'm trying to interact with a smart contract in python. With Metamask i can see, that there is a signature trasferred to verify my wallet.
Now the point is how to calculate this signature to use a python script.
On the contract side, the signature will be compared with a calculated signature on the server:

```
bytes32 message = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, address(this)));
    require(verifier.verify(message, _signature), "INVALID_SIGNATURE");
```

function verify(bytes32 _message, bytes memory _signature) external view returns (bool);

I assume that msg.sender will be my wallet adress but not sure about the other one?

Any links to read more about this topic would also be helpful!
Thank you.

Comment: `keccak256` is a generic hashing function. It can take any string as an input. If your question is about `abi.encodePacked`, you can read about what that does in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/cheatsheet.html?highlight=encodepacked#global-variables).

Answer (score 0):

`Keccak256()`takes in byte arrays (`bytes`) as input.`abi.encodePacked` or `abi.encode` turns input parameters into byte arrays. If by 'the other one', you mean `address(this)`, it refers to the address of the instance of this smart contract. Note that `msg.sender` may not always be an EOA, it might also be a smart contract that invokes the function. It might be helpful to provide more context. In this case, it seems `message` takes in your account address and the smart contract address and create a Hash that compares with `_signature`.